# AWS Lambda API converts JSON to a string

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a challenge of getting my AWS API to return a actual JSON. Everything becomes as one string and all the double quotes in original content are escaped.

I previously had a NodeJS backend with AWS API that worked well. Now, I have not touched the API, but changed the backend to Python and have this problem that did not exist with Node application.

In Python I have Pandas dataframe that that I turn into JSON:

```
myJSON = myDataFrame.to_json(orient = 'records', force_ascii=True)
```

When I print the JSON and check it in the Cloudwatch everything looks OK:

```
[ { "id": "blah blah"  } ]
```

But when I return the result JSON through the API my it comes out completely encapsulated in double quotes which makes it just a string:

```
"[{\"id\":\"blah blah\"}]"
```

I feel dumb, but I don't actually understand if the problem is on the API itself and should some body mapping solve the issue? Or is this about how Pandas formats the JSON -- Why did I not have the problem with nodeJS application as the integration with exact same API?

Comment: Can you try invoking the lambda function directly? Using the console test option or using the CLI http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html.

Comment: It was after all API problem as having the body mapping template t like this `{"myoutput":$input.path('$')}` worked. I still do not know why I had to change that for Python version or maybe the correct question is why did the node version work without that.

Comment: From my experience so far the _default_ behaviour for pandas in api-gateway is that the data frame has to be 'modified' via `to_json`, but then _also_ has to be passed through `json.dumps()`. I _do not_ understand why though as this _appears_ to double encode the json , but only for dataframes. So if someone could shed some light on that I'd be greatful.